# WP7 - Determine if culture is imperial or metric

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, cultureinfo

I'm trying to determine whether or not the user would prefer metric or imperial units in my app.

Is there anyway to do this? I've been trying with CultureInfo to no avail.

Cheers,

Cameron.

Comment: Q: Do you have a "RegionInfo" with an "IsMetric" property?

Comment: Please let the user change it. All my OSes are in English, yet I don't grok imperial system. It is simpler with WP7 native apps where you have an option in system to change the unit, but if you make a webapp for WP7 let the user change it.

Comment: I agree with @lukas; in general it's best to allow the choice as a user preference. I would suggest, however, that you should *default* to the user's current region.

Comment: Already done that. I just needed to set the default unit on first start up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`RegionInfo.IsMetric`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.ismetric.aspx)

Comment: RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.IsMetric. Thanks!